# AWK: get file name from LS

Tags: regex, awk

I have a list of file names (name plus extension) and I want to extract the name only without the extension.

I'm using

```
ls -l | awk '{print $9}'
```

to list the file names and then

```
ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | awk /(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)/'{print $1}'
```

But I get an error on escaping the `(`:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The regex `(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)` to isolate the name has a capture group and I think it is correct,  while I don't get is not working within awk syntax.

My list of files is like this `ABCDEF.ext` in the root folder.

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls` !](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: okay, but the error here is not caused by that one, since it has been already parsed by `awk '{print $9}' `, isn'it?

Comment: No, parsing the output of `ls` isn't causing your immediate error, but it's likely to cause some others along the road. The linked article showcases a few way to deal with lists of files you might want to adopt instead of `ls`, which would make fixing your current error unnecessary :)

Comment: Why aren't there quotes around the regex?

Comment: because I was wrong about `awk` syntax: `awk 'condition{action}'`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this.

```
ls -l | awk '{ s=""; for (i=9;i<=NF;i++) { s = s" "$i }; sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",s); print s}'
```

Notes:

1. read the ls -l output is weird
2. It doesn't check the items (they are files? directories? ... strip extentions everywhere)
3. Read the other answers :D

Comment: @loretoparisi It's really not - there is absolutely no need to use `ls -l` and as numerous people including myself have mentioned, it is problematic.

Comment: You have GOT to be kidding. This is every bit as bad as that awk+sed answer you had previously accepted but just in different ways. Among other things it'll convert **all** chains of contiguous white space in file names to a single blank char each, and it'll still fail by starting at the wrong string given the different timestamp formats that `ls -l` outputs.

Answer (score 5):

Your specific error is caused by the fact that your awk command is incorrectly quoted. The single quotes should go around the whole command, not just the `{ action }` block.

However, you cannot use capture groups like that in awk. `$1` refers to the first field, as defined by the input field separator (which in this case is the default: one or more "blank" characters). It has nothing to do with the parentheses in your regex.

Furthermore, you shouldn't start from `ls -l` to process your files. I think that in this case your best bet would be to use a shell loop:

```
for file in *; do
  printf '%s\n' "${file%.*}"
done
```

This uses the shell's built-in capability to expand `*` to the list of everything in the current directory and removes the `.*` from the end of each name using a standard parameter expansion.

---

If you really really want to use awk for some reason, and all your files have the same extension `.ext`, then I guess you could do something like this:

```
printf '%s\0' * | awk -v RS='\0' '{ sub(/\.ext$/, "") } 1'
```

This prints all the paths in the current directory, and uses awk to remove the suffix. Each path is followed by a null byte `\0` - this is the safe way to pass lists of paths, which in principle could contain any other character.

Slightly less robust but probably fine in most cases would be to trust that no filenames contain a newline, and use `\n` to separate the list:

```
printf '%s\n' * | awk '{ sub(/\.ext$/, "") } 1'
```

Note that the standard tool for simple substitutions like this one would be sed:

```
printf '%s\n' * | sed 's/\.ext$//'
```

Comment: right `$1` does not match the capture group infact, that is why it is not working the fixed one `ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | awk '/(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)/{print $0}'`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but anything starting with `ls -l |` and multiple `awk`s is almost certainly not the best solution. I suggest you try out the loop in my answer.

Comment: I partially agree, because my question was about using `awk` with `ls`. I agree that `ls` is the wrong choice, but strictly answering this question (should) implies the use of `ls` plus `awk`, but you were absolutely right about the optimal answer.

Answer (score 1):

`(.+?)` is a PCRE construct. awk uses EREs, not PCREs. Also you have the opening script delimiter `'` in the middle of the script AFTER the condition instead of where it belongs, before the start of the script.

The syntax for any command (awk, sed, grep, whatever) is `command 'script'` so this should be is `awk 'condition{action}'`, not `awk condition'{action}'`.

But, in any case, as mentioned by @Aaron in the comments - don't parse the output of `ls`, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: thanks for some reason by the way I don't get it working like `ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | awk '/(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)/{print $0}'`.

Comment: `for some reason`? I told you at least one reason: `(.+?)` is a PCRE construct and awk uses EREs, not PCREs. Since you haven't provide any sample input or expected output or told us what it is you're trying to do or in what way that isn't working, there's nothing more I can do to help you debug it or do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way (other then reiterate don't parse the output of ls).

Comment: sorry, files are as simple as `ABCD.ext` and I want to get `ABCD` only. Thanks for the clarification I was not aware of `EREs` and `PCRE`, but how to handle `(.+?)` in EREs? thanks.

Comment: Provide all relevant information in your question, don't spread it out across comments. As for `how to handle (.+?) in EREs` - `(.+?)` is an answer to a question, it's not the question. Given that `Y` is a solution for question `X`, you need to be asking `how do I do X?` not `how do I do Y in some other way?`. See http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score -2):

If the extension is always the same pattern try a sed replacement:

```
ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | sed 's\.ext$\\'
```

Comment: `ls -l | awk '{print $9}'` is not a good idea since the output of `ls -l` is not standardised between systems and something as trivial as a filename with a space will cause this command to break.

Comment: Even just a different timestamp will cause it to break. Also, you never need sed when you're using awk since awk can do anything sed can do and that sed command has it's slashes going in the wrong direction so I'm surprised it's not producing a syntax error and it's using the `.` as a BRE metacharacter so it'll remove the wrong part of any file name that contains `ext` in the middle of it. Try  `echo 'context.ext' | sed 's\.ext\\'` and you'll see it output `con.ext`. This is the wrong approach implemented the wrong way with bugs.